ngx-uploader is not working on Angular 16 app
I'm trying to create a sophisticated file uploader using Angular 16 frontend with a Laravel 11 backend, and i searched and found that ngx-uploader is suitable for the options i need in my file uploader (using drag-and-drop and file browser, showing uplaod progress bar, total number of files and how many been uploaded so far, list of succesfully uploaded files)
but i dont seem to be able to make it work for some reason i find it complicated
i tried different things, like modifying, my component code; the interfaces.d.ts code, i also looked for tutrials but nothing helped, let me share my code with you :
<app-alert></app-alert>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row py-5">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="upload-container">
        <h2>{{('Upload.Upload' | translate)}}</h2>

        <!-- Drop Container -->
        <div class="drop-container" ngFileDrop [options]="options" (uploadOutput)="onUploadOutput($event)"
          [uploadInput]="uploadInput" [ngClass]="{ 'is-drop-over': dragOver }">
          <div class="upload-icon">
            <img src="assets/imgs/Upload icon.svg" alt="Upload Icon">
          </div>
          <h3>{{('Upload.Drag & drop files or' | translate)}}
            <label class="browse-link" (click)="onBrowseClick()">{{('Upload.Browse' | translate)}}</label>
          </h3>
          <p class="supported-formats">{{('Upload.Supported formats: PDF, Word and PPT' | translate)}}</p>
          <input type="file" #fileInput ngFileSelect [options]="options" (uploadOutput)="onUploadOutput($event)"
            [uploadInput]="uploadInput" multiple hidden />
        </div>

        <!-- Completed Upload Count -->
        <div class="upload-status">
            Uploading - {{ completedUploads }}/{{ files.length }} files
        </div>


        <!-- File List with Progress and Error Messages -->
        <div class="file-list">
          <h3 *ngIf="files.length>0">Uploaded</h3>
          <div *ngFor="let file of files" class="file-item"
            [ngClass]="{'error': file.errorStatus, 'success': file.progress?.status === UploadStatus.Done}">
            <span>{{ file.name }}</span>
            <!-- Remove button for each file -->
            <button class="remove-btn" (click)="removeFile(file.id)">
              <i class="bi bi-trash3"></i>
            </button>
            <!-- Display progress for each file -->
            <div *ngIf="file.progress?.status === UploadStatus.Uploading" class="progress-bar">
              <div class="progress" [style.width.%]="file.progress?.data?.percentage"></div>
              <span>{{ file.progress?.data?.percentage }}%</span>
            </div>
            <!-- Error message in red if there's an error -->
            <span *ngIf="file.errorStatus" class="error-message">
              {{ file.errorMessage || 'Upload failed'}}
            </span>
          </div>

        </div>

        <!-- Upload Button -->
        <app-button-green (click)="startUpload()">Upload File</app-button-green>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


here is my ts file:
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, ElementRef, EventEmitter, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { UploadOutput, UploadInput, UploadFile, UploaderOptions, UploadStatus } from 'ngx-uploader';
import { ProfileUpdateService } from 'src/app/services/profile-update.service';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment.development';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-upload-file',
  templateUrl: './upload-file.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./upload-file.component.css']
})
export class UploadFileComponent {
  options: UploaderOptions;
  files: UploadFile[] = [];
  uploadInput: EventEmitter<UploadInput>;
  dragOver?: boolean;
  uploadUrl = `${environment.apiUrl}/upload_files`; // Adjust your API URL as needed
  @ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput!: ElementRef; // Reference to the file input
  completedUploads: number = 0;
  user_id=0;
  public UploadStatus = UploadStatus; // Make UploadStatus available in template

  constructor(private userService: ProfileUpdateService) {
    this.options = { concurrency: 1, maxUploads: 3, maxFileSize: 1000000, allowedContentTypes:['.pdf','.docx','.pdf','.pptx'] }; // Adjust options based on needs
    this.uploadInput = new EventEmitter<UploadInput>(); // Initialize the event emitter
    this.fetchUserId();
  }

  fetchUserId(): void {
    this.userService.getUser().subscribe(response => {
      this.user_id = response.id; // Store user ID in a class variable
    });
  }

  onUploadOutput(output: UploadOutput): void {
    switch (output.type) {
      case 'addedToQueue':
        if (typeof output.file !== 'undefined') {
          this.files.push(output.file);
        }
        break;

      case 'allAddedToQueue':
        this.startUpload(); // Start the upload process after adding files
        break;

      case 'uploading':
        if (typeof output.file !== 'undefined') {
          // update current data in files array for uploading file
          const index = this.files.findIndex(file => typeof output.file !== 'undefined' && file.id === output.file.id);
          this.files[index] = output.file;
        }
        break;

      case 'removed':
        // remove file from array when removed
        this.files = this.files.filter((file: UploadFile) => file !== output.file);
        break;
      case 'dragOver':
        this.dragOver = true;
        break;
      case 'dragOut':
      case 'drop':
        this.dragOver = false;
        break;
      case 'done':
        // The file is downloaded
        break;

    }
  }

  updateCompletedUploads() {
    this.completedUploads = this.files.filter(file => file.progress?.status === UploadStatus.Done).length; // Count completed uploads
  }

  startUpload(): void {
    const uploadEvent: UploadInput = {
      type: 'uploadAll',
      url: this.uploadUrl,
      method: 'POST',
      user_id: this.user_id
    };
    this.uploadInput.emit(uploadEvent); // Emit the upload event
  }

  removeFile(id: string): void {
    this.files = this.files.filter(file => file.id !== id); // Remove file from list
    this.updateCompletedUploads(); // Update completed uploads count
  }

  onBrowseClick(): void {
    this.fileInput.nativeElement.click(); // Trigger the hidden file input
  }
}


here is the interfaces file:
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

export interface UploaderOptions {
    concurrency: number;
    allowedContentTypes?: string[];
    maxUploads?: number;
    maxFileSize?: number;
}

export interface BlobFile extends Blob {
    name: string;
}

export declare enum UploadStatus {
    Queue = 0,
    Uploading = 1,
    Done = 2,
    Cancelled = 3
}

export interface UploadProgress {
    status: UploadStatus;
    data?: {
        percentage: number;
        speed: number;
        speedHuman: string;
        startTime: number | null;
        endTime: number | null;
        eta: number | null;
        etaHuman: string | null;
    };
}

export interface UploadFile {
    id: string;
    fileIndex?: number;
    lastModifiedDate?: Date;
    name?: string;
    file_size?: number;
    type?: string;
    form?: FormData;
    progress?: UploadProgress;
    response?: any;
    responseStatus?: number;
    sub?: Subscription | any;
    nativeFile?: File;
    responseHeaders?: {
        [key: string]: string;
    };
  errorStatus?: boolean;  // Add this line
  errorMessage?: string;  // Add this if you need an error message
}

export interface UploadOutput {
    type: 'addedToQueue' | 'allAddedToQueue' | 'uploading' | 'done' | 'start' | 'cancelled' | 'dragOver' | 'dragOut' | 'drop' | 'removed' | 'removedAll' | 'rejected';
    file?: UploadFile;
    nativeFile?: File;
}

export interface UploadInput {
    type: 'uploadAll' | 'uploadFile' | 'cancel' | 'cancelAll' | 'remove' | 'removeAll';
    url?: string;
    method?: string;
    id?: string;
    fieldName?: string;
    fileIndex?: number;
    user_id?: number;
    file?: UploadFile;
    data?: {
        [key: string]: string | Blob;
    };
    headers?: {
        [key: string]: string;
    };
    includeWebKitFormBoundary?: boolean;
    withCredentials?: boolean;
}


and here is my laravel function :
public function upload(UploadedFileRequest $request)
    {

        try {
            // Initialize an array to hold the paths of uploaded files
            $filePaths = [];

            if ($request->hasfile('filePaths')) {
                $count = 0;
                foreach ($request->file('filePaths') as $file) {
                    $f = new UploadedFile();
                    $f->user_id = $file->user_id;
                    $f->file_size = $file->file_size;

                    $fileName = str_replace(' ', '', $file->getClientOriginalName() . '(' . time() . ').' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension());
                    $f->file_path = $file->storeAs('uploadedFiles', $fileName);
                    $f->save();
                    $count++;
                    $filePaths[] = $f->file_path;
                }
            }

            // Return a successful response with the file paths
            return response()->json([
                'message' => __('exceptions.Files uploaded successfully'),
                'paths' => $filePaths,
            ]);
        } catch (Error $e) {
            Log::error('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
            return response()->json([__('validation.error') => $e->getMessage()], 422);
        } catch (\Throwable $e) {
            Log::error('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
            return response()->json([__('validation.error') => $e->getMessage()], 422);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::error('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
            return response()->json([__('validation.error') => $e->getMessage()], 422);
        }
    }


well let me share what worked for me incase it could help someone:
import { Component, ElementRef, EventEmitter, ViewChild } from 

'@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { UploadOutput, UploadInput, UploadFile, UploaderOptions, UploadStatus } from 'ngx-uploader';
import { AlertService } from 'src/app/services/alert.service';
import { LoaderService } from 'src/app/services/loader.service';
import { UploadService } from 'src/app/services/upload.service';
import { AlertComponent } from 'src/app/shared/alert/alert.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-upload-file',
  templateUrl: './upload-file.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./upload-file.component.css']
})
export class UploadFileComponent {
  options: UploaderOptions;
  files: UploadFile[] = [];
  error: any= [];
  uploadInput: EventEmitter<UploadInput>;
  @ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput!: ElementRef; // Reference to the file input
  dragOver: boolean = true;
  rejectedFiles: UploadFile[] = []; // Array for rejected files

  UploadStatus = UploadStatus; // Make UploadStatus available in template
  @ViewChild(AlertComponent) customAlert!: AlertComponent;

  constructor(private uploadService: UploadService,
              private loaderService: LoaderService,
              private translate: TranslateService,
              private alertService: AlertService) {
    this.options = { concurrency: 1, allowedContentTypes: ['application/pdf'] }; // Adjust options based on needs
    this.uploadInput = new EventEmitter<UploadInput>(); // Initialize the event emitter
   }

  onUploadOutput(output: UploadOutput): void {
    switch (output.type) {
      case 'addedToQueue':
        if (output.file) {
          output.file.errorStatus = false;
          output.file.errorMessage = '';
          this.files.push(output.file);
        }
        break;

      case 'uploading':
        if (typeof output.file !== 'undefined') {
          // update current data in files array for uploading file
          const index = this.files.findIndex(file => typeof output.file !== 'undefined' && file.id === output.file.id);
          this.files[index] = output.file;
        }
        break;

      case 'removed':
        // remove file from array when removed
        this.files = this.files.filter((file: UploadFile) => file !== output.file);
        break;
      case 'dragOver':
        this.dragOver = true;
        break;
      case 'dragOut':
      case 'drop':
        this.dragOver = false;
        break;
      case 'done':
        // The file is downloaded
        break;

      case 'rejected':

        if (output.file) {
          output.file.errorStatus = true;

           if (output.file.type && output.file.type !== 'application/pdf') {
            output.file.errorMessage = this.translate.instant('Upload.This document is not supported, please delete it and upload another file.');
           }
          // Add to the rejected files array
          this.rejectedFiles.push(output.file);
        }
        break;

    }
  }

  startUpload(): void {
    this.loaderService.setLoading(true);

    // Filter out any undefined values and only get the native files
    const filesToUpload = this.files
      .map(file => file.nativeFile)
      .filter((file): file is File => file !== undefined);

    this.uploadService.uploadFiles(filesToUpload) // Send the native file object
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          if (response.status === 'success') {
            this.loaderService.setLoading(false);

            this.customAlert.alertType = 'success';
            this.customAlert.title = this.translate.instant('alert.Successful Upload');
            this.customAlert.message = this.translate.instant('alert.Your files has been uploaded successfully, you can now edit the files easily');
            this.customAlert.showPrimaryButton = true;
            this.customAlert.primaryButtonLabel = this.translate.instant('alert.Back');
            this.customAlert.primaryButtonRoute = "/upload_file";

            this.customAlert.showSecondaryButton = true;
            this.customAlert.secondaryButtonLabel = this.translate.instant('alert.View Uploaded Files');
            this.customAlert.secondaryButtonRoute = "/my_uploaded_files";
            this.customAlert.openModal();
            this.alertService.clearAlert();
          }
        },
        error => {
            this.loaderService.setLoading(false);
          // Handle validation errors
          if (error.error && Array.isArray(error.error.errors)) {
            // Convert array of validation errors to a single string message
            this.error = error.error.errors.join(', ');
          } else if (error.error && error.error.message) {
            // Handle general error messages
            this.error = error.error.message;
          } else {
            // Default error message if none is provided
            this.error = 'TOAST.An unexpected error occurred';
          }

          // Configure and display the custom alert
          this.customAlert.alertType = "error";
          this.customAlert.title = this.translate.instant('TOAST.Error');
          this.customAlert.message = this.translate.instant(this.error);
          this.customAlert.primaryButtonLabel = this.translate.instant('TOAST.Close');
          this.customAlert.showSecondaryButton = false;
          this.customAlert.openModal();
        }
      );
  }


  removeFile(id: string): void {
    this.files = this.files.filter(file => file.id !== id); // Remove file from list
  }

  removeRejectedFile(id: string): void {
    this.rejectedFiles = this.rejectedFiles.filter(file => file.id !== id); // Remove file from list
  }

  onBrowseClick(): void {
    this.fileInput.nativeElement.click(); // Trigger the hidden file input
  }
}

and here is my html :
 <app-alert></app-alert>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row py-5">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="upload-container">
        <h2>{{('Upload.Upload' | translate)}}</h2>

        <!-- Drop Container -->
        <div class="drop-container" ngFileDrop [options]="options" (uploadOutput)="onUploadOutput($event)"
          [uploadInput]="uploadInput" [ngClass]="{ 'is-drop-over': dragOver }">
          <div class="upload-icon">
            <img src="assets/imgs/Upload icon.svg" alt="Upload Icon">
          </div>
          <h3>{{('Upload.Drag & drop files or' | translate)}}
            <label class="browse-link" (click)="onBrowseClick()">{{('Upload.Browse' | translate)}}</label>
          </h3>
          <p class="supported-formats">{{('Upload.Supported formats: PDF, Word and PPT' | translate)}}</p>
          <input type="file" #fileInput accept=".pdf" ngFileSelect [options]="options" (uploadOutput)="onUploadOutput($event)"
            [uploadInput]="uploadInput" multiple hidden />
        </div>

        <!-- Rejected Files Section -->
        <div class="rejected-file-list" *ngIf="rejectedFiles.length > 0">
          <div *ngFor="let file of rejectedFiles">
            <div class="file-item error">
              <span>{{ file.name }}</span>
              <button class="remove-btn" (click)="removeRejectedFile(file.id)">
                <i class="bi bi-x-circle-fill"></i>
              </button>
            </div>
            <p class="error-message">{{ file.errorMessage }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- File List with Progress and Error Messages -->
        <div class="file-list">
          <h3 *ngIf="files.length>0">
            {{('Upload.Uploaded' | translate )}}: {{ files.length }}/{{ files.length }} {{('Upload.files' | translate)}}
          </h3>
          <div *ngFor="let file of files" class="file-item"
            [ngClass]="{'error': file.errorStatus, 'success': file.progress?.status === UploadStatus.Done}">
            <span>{{ file.name }}</span>
            <p *ngIf="file.errorStatus" class="error-message">{{ file.errorMessage }}</p>

            <!-- Remove button for each file -->
            <button class="remove-btn" (click)="removeFile(file.id)">
              <i class="bi bi-trash3"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Upload Button -->
        <app-button-green (click)="startUpload()">{{('Upload.Upload File' | translate)}}</app-button-green>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

and here is my service:
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { TokenService } from './authentification/token.service';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment.development';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UploadService {
  private baseUrl: string = environment.apiUrl;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private tokenService: TokenService) { }

  uploadFiles(files: File[]): Observable<any> {
    const language = localStorage.getItem('lang') || 'Ar';
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Accept-Language': language
    });
    const formData = new FormData();

    files.forEach((file) => {
      formData.append('files[]', file, file.name);
    });



    const userId = this.tokenService.getUserId();  // Get the current user's ID
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/upload_files/${userId}`, formData, { headers});
  }
}

and here is my controller:
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\UploadedFileRequest;
use App\Models\UploadedFile;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class UploadedFileController extends Controller
{
    public function upload(UploadedFileRequest $request, $user_id)
    {
        try{
        $filePaths = []; // Array to store paths of uploaded files

        // Ensure 'files' exist in the request
        if ($request->hasFile('files')) {
            foreach ($request->file('files') as $file) {
                $f = new UploadedFile();
                $f->user_id = $user_id;
                $f->file_size = $file->getSize(); // Set file size

                // Generate unique file name and save file
                $filePath = $file->storeAs('uploadedFiles/'. $user_id, $file->getClientOriginalName(), 'public'); // Store in 'public/uploadedFiles'

                $f->file_path = $filePath; // Save file path to model
                $f->save(); // Save the model to database

                $filePaths[] = $filePath; // Add path to response
            }
        }

        // Successful response with uploaded file paths
        return response()->json([
            'status'=> 'success',
            'message' => __('exceptions.Files uploaded successfully'),
            'paths' => $filePaths,
        ], 200);

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::error('Error during file upload: ' . $e->getMessage());
            return response()->json([
                'error' => 'Failed to upload files',
                'error' => $e->getMessage(),
            ], 500);
        }
    }

    public function getMyUploadedFiles($id)
    {
        try {
            $files = UploadedFile::Where('user_id', $id)->With('user')->get();
            return response()->json($files);

        } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
            // Log specific error message but return a generic not found message
            Log::error('Files not found: ' . $e->getMessage());
            return response()->json(['error' => __('exceptions.File not found.')], 404); // 404 Not Found

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Catch any other exceptions and log them
            Log::error('Error fetching files: ' . $e->getMessage());
            return response()->json(['error' => __('exceptions.An error occurred while fetching the file.')], 500); // 500 Internal Server Error
        }
    }

}

